# Addition 2 number in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I got problem with array when i want make addition of 2 first number. 
What I doing wrong ?

```
$items = array('b' => 10,'a' => 10, 31, 51));

$sum = 0;
foreach ($items as $value) {
    $sum = $item['a'] + $item['b'];
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: For each loop is not required at all to sum the first 2 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some syntax erros in your code i.e. you have defined **$items** as array and you are using **$item**, also some extra brackets. I have just modified your code, see below

```
$items = array('a' => 10,'b' => 30, 'c' =>31, 'd' =>51);

$sum = 0;
foreach ($items as $value) {
    $sum = $items['a'] + $items['b'];
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: I think for each loop is not required at all to sum the first 2 elements.

Comment: Yes, it is not required, but @Mati Urbaniak logic is also working using foreach

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_sum](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [array_slice](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function to sum the first two element

```
$sum = array_sum(array_slice($originalArray, 0, 2, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

simple write below and its work

```
$items = array('b' => 10,'a' => 10, 31, 51);
$sum = $items['b'] + $items['a'];
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

just use addition instead of executing a loop.

```
$sum = $items['a'] + $items['b'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any loop.

Just sum the array items based on the key.

```
$sum = $items['b'] + $items['a'];
```

You might need to use [array_key_exists](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_key_exists.asp) to avoid the exception if the key is not available. I would do it like this

```
$sum = (array_key_exists('a',$items['a'])?$items['a']:0) +
       (array_key_exists('b',$items['b'])?$items['b']:0);
```

If key exists, use the value else add 0.